# In a square grid ($6 \times 6$) that comprises 25 small unit squares each of side 1 cm, how many rectangles (not squares) are there in the grid?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This comes under Combinatorics under intersection of parallel lines. I calculated the number of rectangles to be $\binom62 \times \binom62 = 225$. But how does one subtract only the number of squares from this number? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Count the squares according to their sizes. There is one square of side $5$, and there are $5^2=25$ of side $1$. How many are there of sides $4,3$, and $2$? (It’s probably easiest to count them in that order, but you should see a pattern pretty quickly.)

It may help to realize that when you’re counting squares of side $k$, once you choose the top and lefthand edges, there’s nothing left to choose: the bottom and righthand edges have to be $k$ units down and over, respectively. Of course this does put some limitations on which edges you can choose for the top and lefthand side.

**Added:** Indeed, you can carry this same idea further: once you know where the upper lefthand corner is, you know the whole square. How many places are there for the upper lefthand corner of a square of side $k$? It has to be at least $k$ units from the bottom and at least $k$ units from the righthand edge. How many vertices fit that description?

Comment: That was where the confusion started. I could calculate the number of squares of sides 5 and 1 but am making a mistake in calculating the number of squares of side 4, 3 and 2. Even tried drawing the grid but i am ending up overcounting. Is there another way?

Comment: @Sharon: You’re going to have to count by size, but I just realized that the counting itself can be made a little easier, so that you should spot the pattern a little quicker. To get you started, there are $4$ squares of side $4$.

Comment: Oh yes there is a pattern! I got it. Thanks @Brian.

Comment: @Sharon: Great! You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianDoes this pattern hold true for all mXm type of square grids?

Comment: @Sharon: Yes, it does. Think about the requirement that the northwest corner of a square of side $k$ must be at least $k$ units from the right and bottom edges of the big square: it forces the northwest corner into a square region in the northwest part of the big square, one whose size you can compute if you know $k$ and the size of the big square. If the big square is $n\times n$ (in terms of lines, not area), the northwest corner of a square of side $k$ must lie on one of the first $n-k$ grid lines counting from the left and also counting from the top, so there are $(n-k)^2$ such squares.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the squares. The number of $1\times 1$ squares is $5^2$. 
The number of $2\times 2$ squares is $4^2$. The number of $3\times 3$ squares is $3^2$. The number of $4\times 4$ squares is $2^2$. And finally there are (is?) $1^2$ square that is $5\times 5$.

Add up to get what you need to subtract from the total count of the rectangles.

To see that there are, for example, $2^2$ $4\times 4$ squares, note that the northwest corner of such a square can be in any grid position in a certain square at the northwest corner.

The idea genralizes. We can even use it to count the number of squares in a rectangular $m\times n$ array.